# Legend in two rows in R using bquote

Tags: r, plot, legend

I want to plot the legend using `bquote`, but I have a problem adding two rows in my legend. For example:

This works:

```
plot(1:10)
r2=0.99
legend("topleft",legend=bquote(R^{2} ~ "="  ~.(r2)),bty = "n")
```

[image]

But if I add a second row:

```
plot(1:10)
r2=0.99
pval=0.01
legend("topleft",legend=c(bquote(R^{2} ~ "="  ~.(r2)),paste("P-value =",pval)),bty = "n")
```

The whole first element of my vector in legend is "expanded". Why is that?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because  `c`-function cannot concatenate multiple instances of the object type returned by `bquote`. Most people think that `bquote` returns R expressions, but it does not. It returns calls and they don't concatenate into lists. You need to apply the `expression` function to items returned by multiple calls to `bquote` to get them into an 'expression'-list. This was explained by Thomas Lumley on Rhelp in 2005:

```
legend("topleft",legend=do.call( 'expression', 
                                list( bquote( R^{2} == .(r2)), 
                                      bquote( "P-value" == .(pval)))  ),
                  bty = "n")
```

[image]

There is an alternate approach if you wnat to build this argument to legend, that would allow stringing expressions together with `c()`. Redefine bquote to return an expression:

```
bquote2 <- function (expr, where = parent.frame()) 
{
    unquote <- function(e) if (is.pairlist(e)) 
        as.pairlist(lapply(e, unquote))
    else if (length(e) <= 1L) 
        e
    else if (e[[1L]] == as.name(".")) 
        eval(e[[2L]], where)
    else as.call(lapply(e, unquote))
    as.expression( unquote(substitute(expr)) )
}
legend("topleft",
        legend=c( bquote2(R^{2} ~ "="  ~.(r2)),
                  bquote2(paste("P-value =",pval))), 
        bty = "n")
```

Comment: Ah! I figured that they were language objects, but I didn't know they could be combined like this.

Comment: If bquote did return an expression, I believe you would be able to use `c` since expression lists are list-like-objects. I'll see if I can make a modification to its code.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to produce something like what you want with the following:

```
textleg <- substitute(atop(paste(R^2==k),
                           plain(P-value)==j), list(k = r2, j=pval))
legend("topleft",legend=textleg,bty = "n")
```

[image]

EDIT:

@42- made the suggestion that adding quotes would turn my minus sign in 'P-value' to a hyphen:

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's pretty close. I'm just still annoyed about the rows not being aligned properly :P

Comment: (Really minor point): I agree with your effort to use more plotmath operators but the minus sign between the `P` and `value` is getting spread wider than it would if you had quoted "P-value".